# http live streaming (HLS): mixing streams and playlists in index file

Tags: iphone, http, streaming, live, http-live-streaming

I'm implementing a small HLS playlist parser.  I was wondering if a variant playlist could also contain streams.

I.e. Is the following allowed?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2680

#EXTINF:8, 
https://priv.example.com/fileSequence2680.ts

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1280000
http://example.com/low.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2560000
http://example.com/mid.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=7680000
http://example.com/hi.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=65000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5"
http://example.com/audio-only.m3u8
```

It doesn't really make sense but the spec doesn't explicitly say it's not allowed.

If it were allowed, I would expect a player to play fileSequence2680.ts then files from low.m3u8, mid.m3u8, hi.m3u8 or audio-only.m3u8 depending on the bandwidth.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Passing such a playlist through Apple's mediastreamvalidator is probably the best way to fond out if this is supported (I doubt it).